# Generating a static ranged integer value based on an array of bytes

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay, this is a strange one I believe, and I have absolutely no idea of how to go about it.

So basically what I'm looking for is a way to generate a fixed ranged integer value based on a given array of bytes.

Say I have an array named imALonleyArray

```
unsigned char imALonleyArray[16] = {0x33, 0x7E, 0xD5, 0x8F, 0xC3, 0x01, 0x39, 0x0C, 0x5B, 0x0F, 0x80, 0x9C, 0x78, 0x90, 0x89, 0xF5};
```

I'd like to somehow generate a static ranged integer value based on the above array.

Why you might ask?
I need to assign a fixed int value from possibly int_min to int_max or, really for this program (0-1487) based on a given users 16 byte session token.

Example:

```
int getIntRangeFromGivenBytes(unsigned char *arr, int minValue, int maxValue){
    /*Magic here that somehow computes then returns an int value between 
    minValue and maxValue based on the given bytes provided by the 'arr' argument*/  
}
```

I tried my best to describe what I'm trying to do here. I'm a newb here, please don't shoot me down.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'd like to somehow generate a static ranged integer value based on the above array." generate. how? "What I mean by a 'static ranged integer' is a fixed integer between a set range of x and x that will compute the same value." what is x? "compute" how? "same value" as what? Sorry but your question is very unclear.

Comment: x was used as an example, being int_min to int_max values. I'm looking to generate a ranged number based on a given array. Same value meaning each time it's computed it will return the same generated int value.

Comment: Well, just `|` them toghether and you have an `int` between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: What you are looking for may be a hash: you give a function 64 bits, and it gives you an integer between 0-1487. For same input, you will always get same output, but those hashes will collide if you got enough sessions.

Comment: well that doesn't make any sense. It seems as maybe you're not understanding me at all?

I'd like to put together some type of function wich generates a ranged int value based on a given 16 byte array.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you for understanding what I'm trying to do. Exactly like a hash, I thought it would sound very funny describing it that way. Collision is okay here, so I don't need to worry about the data being exactly 100% unique, but it must return the same value each and every time based on the given input.

Comment: @Swordfish, thanks for making me feel brainless! it was a very easy question. No need to troll around for being inexperienced and looking for help to better improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're asking for an algorithm that for a given char array, generate an integer within a given range [a,b], where the same integer will pop up for the same input.

A really easy and simple one would be to add them all together and use % modulo to get it into the range.

```cpp
int interval = maxValue - minValue;
int increment = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i){
    increment += array[i];
    increment = increment % interval; // this ensures output is always within the interval
}

int final_answer = increment + a;
```

If you want one that's reversible, that'd be different. And frankly impossible if there's more possible arrangements of the array than there are elements in the interval. (If two different arrays map to the same integer, how do you reverse it?)

An example, let's say you have interval [0,5].

```cpp
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x00}; // assign to 0
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x01}; // assign to 1
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x02}; // assign to 2
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x03}; // assign to 3
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x04}; // assign to 4
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x05}; // assign to 5
unsigned char array[2] = {0x00, 0x06}; // now what?
```

So you need to make sure that the interval is large enough, or limit the size of the char array enough that there's no collisions.

sidenote: the word `static` means something *very* specific in C++, so your question was a bit confusing.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! does exactly as asked for.

Comment: Note that there are better algorithms for preventing collisions, and you may want to do bounds checking to make sure nothing overflows.

Comment: A collision is okay, the value does not have to be entirely unique. I've limited the input to 5 bytes. As for checking the bounds of the array, the array given will always be a fixed 5 bytes :)

Comment: Sidenote: thanks for the side note :) you're entirely right, to some that would be misunderstood as a static data type, I suppose for lack of better words that 'fixed' is more appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

You want a hash, and a simple hash on values that are numeric integer types to some range is division:

```
uint64_t to_value(const uint8_t *array) {
  uint64_t result = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
    result = (result << 8) | array[i];
  return result;
}

uint64_t to_range(uint64_t input, uint64_t lower, uint64_t upper) {
  if (lower > upper)
    std::swap(upper, lower);
  if (upper == std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() &&
      lower == std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::min())
    return input;
  auto range = upper - lower + 1;
  return lower + ((input - lower) / range);
}
```

Use:

```
uint64_t my_hash(const uint8_t *data) {
  auto value = to_value(data);
  return to_range(value, 0, 1487);
}
```

Whether such a hash has some other properties that you haven’t listed is another story. But it fulfills the requirements you state.

Comment: This is a very clever method of exactly what I asked for, however, I forgot I needed to port for c# use too. I'm going to stick with @ChilliDoughnuts answer as it's simple and does the trick and I'm not too concerned about collision. Thank you for the effort! I will keep this in mind for future needs.